# How to padding between images in background: repeat using CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a background with repeated image using CSS

```
background:  url(../images/bg.PNG) repeat;
```

The problem is that the images are very close to each other, how can I add a padding for every image?

Answer (score 6):

```css
html {
  background: white;
}

body {
  width: 639px;
  height: 280px;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) silver;
  background-repeat: space;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, can I determine the size between the images?

Comment: @user1684140, yes: `w = 639, iw = 64, hc = w/iw | 0, hs = w%iw / hc,
h = 280, ih = 64, vc = h/ih | 0, vs = h%ih / vc,
[hs, vs]` is 7px horisontally and 6px vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this is possible, can't you add a transparent space in bg.PNG ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have spaces between the background images. But you can modify your image to have the spaces you want.